# select multiple records based on order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, greatest-n-per-group

i have a table with a bunch of customer IDs. in a customer table is also these IDs but each id can be on multiple records for the same customer. i want to select the most recently used record which i can get by doing `order by <my_field> desc`

say i have 100 customer IDs in this table and in the customers table there is 120 records with these IDs (some are duplicates). how can i apply my `order by` condition to only get the most recent matching records?

dbms is sql server 2000.

table is basically like this:
loc_nbr and cust_nbr are primary keys

a customer shops at location 1. they get assigned loc_nbr = 1 and cust_nbr = 1
then a customer_id of 1.

they shop again but this time at location 2. so they get assigned loc_nbr = 2 and cust_Nbr = 1. then the same customer_id of 1 based on their other attributes like name and address.

because they shopped at location 2 AFTER location 1, it will have a more recent rec_alt_ts value, which is the record i would want to retrieve.

Comment: Can you clarify please?  As it stands, it sounds like you have a Customers table with duplicate Customer IDs, which doesn't sound right.  Maybe you can describe your tables a bit more explicitly. And also tell us which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried already?

Comment: It's still very unclear. I'm surprised some are still trying to give you answers.  But if you want accurate ones, you'll have to put more effort into your post.  Please define your model clearly. Or include the DDL script even if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function with a Common Table Expression (CTE).

Here's a basic example. You should be able to use a similar query with your data.

```
;WITH TheLatest AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group-by-fields ORDER BY sorting-fields) AS ItemCount 
    FROM TheTable 
)
SELECT * 
FROM TheLatest 
WHERE ItemCount = 1
```

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that this was tagged with sql-server-2000. This will only work on SQL Server 2005 and later.

Comment: For SQL Server 2005+, this problem has been asked about and solved (particularly using ROW_NUMBER) a lot of times. So, you are free to leave your answer, of course, but please don't hesitate if you feel like removing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregate function in the query to group by customer IDs:

```
  SELECT cust_Nbr, MAX(rec_alt_ts) AS most_recent_transaction, other_fields
    FROM tableName
GROUP BY cust_Nbr, other_fields
ORDER BY cust_Nbr DESC;
```

This assumes that `rec_alt_ts` increases every time, thus the max entry for that `cust_Nbr` would be the most recent entry.

Comment: loc_nbr won't increase. they could shop at location number 350 and then again at location 10. location number is assigned to a physical store and doesn't have anything to do with when they bought something. rec_alt_ts is a field that is basically when the record was added to the table.  how can i implement the `GROUP BY` when i'm joining it to another table of customer IDs where i want to get the most recent?

Comment: Have you ever tried retrieving columns that are not in GROUP BY in SQL Server? Or what did you mean by `other_fields`?

Comment: You should probably add `other_fields` to the group by or this will not work.

Comment: @Zane Thanks, it's been a while since I've written queries for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give real table and field names, this is just psuedo code for a solution.

```
select * 
from customer_table t2
inner join location_table t1 
  on t1.some_key = t2.some_key
where t1.LocationKey = (select top 1 (LocationKey) as LatestLocationKey from  location_table  where cust_id = t1.cust_id order by some_field)
```

Answer (score -3):

By using time and date we can take out the recent detail for the customer.
use the  column from where you take out the date and the time for the customer.

eg:

SQL> select ename , to_date(hiredate,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from emp order by to_date(hiredate,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

Comment: This is clearly marked as sql server. The to_date function is from Oracle.